# Updating Symantec Enpoint Protection's Proactive Threat Protection Without an Internet Connection

Tags: internet, networking, spyware, symantec, anti-virus

I have a computer that is not connected to the Internet.  I update Symantec Endpoint Protection's Antivirus and Antispyware Protection manually.  The Proactive Threat Protection always says "Waiting for Updates."  How can I update PTP without an Internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/sep-avptpntp-definition-files-client-machines:

It looks like you can copy this directory (or its Windows Vista/7 equivalent) from an updated machine to your other machine.

> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Symantec\SyKnApps

I'm not sure if you have to shut down the SEP during the process, and don't have it available to test, but that looks like a reasonable solution.