# How do I update Symantec Endpoint Protection offline

Tags: updates, symantec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating Symantec Enpoint Protection's Proactive Threat Protection Without an Internet Connection](https://superuser.com/questions/202193/updating-symantec-enpoint-protections-proactive-threat-protection-without-an-in)

I occasionally come across computers that will never be connected to the internet but are still vulnerable to viruses through other sources (ex. thumb drives, software installs, etc).

What I need is a solution where I can drop the updates on the machines, or connect to them directly (via x-over cable) to download the updates locally.

Is this possible?

If it is...

How would I go about setting this up?

Is this option a viable long-term option?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/q/202193/97028) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these clients managed using a SEPM?  Do they have a network connection?  What version of SEP including updates?

You can always download teh latest definitions to a USB drive or other media and sneakernet them to the system.  I know there was a discussion around a tool to do this but cannot find reference to Symantec relasing one

http://www.symantec.com/security_response/definitions/download/detail.jsp?gid=savce

I believe Symantec may now require a license to download definitions for some versions